# Jquery or Javascript string operators add values

Tags: javascript, jquery

In PHP we can give same strings and add different values for the same string, for example:

```
<?php

$test.="1";
$test.="3";
$test.="3";
$test.="4";


print $test;
/// Rsult 1 2 3 4 , .....
?>
```

In Javascript or Jquery, we don´t know how I can do the same. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
        function pag_slider()
        {
        n_sliders=4;
        for(p=0;p<n_sliders;p++)
        {
        pg+="<span>"+p+"</span>";
        }


        jQuery(".pag_sli").html("<span>"+pg+"</span>");

    /// I can´t show in div 1 2 3 4 
        }

        </script>
```

The problem it´s don´t show me for example in the case o jquery the results as for example in php , 1 2 3 4 , etc, i don´t know why

Thank´s for the help best regards

Comment: Did you try to google string concatenation in javascript?  This is a really simple operation that will turn up lots of search results.

Comment: I mean, you are already doing it in your snippet....  `pg+="<span>"+p+"</span>"`.  Two forms of string concatenation right there.

Comment: ok but i try and don´t show in div 1 2 3 4 , etc howewer i put something bad

Comment: Where is `n_sliders` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Here is little modifications in your JS code:

```js
function pag_slider(n_sliders) {
    var pg = "";
    for (var p = 1; p <= n_sliders; p++) {
        pg += "<span>" + p + "</span>";
    }

    document.write(pg);
}

pag_slider(5);
```

result:

> 12345

https://jsfiddle.net/8twx4ex3/

Comment: if jquery can't find the target element in DOM, then its entirely different problem. You need to debug this better

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you need to define a string before you can append to it. So you have to declare `pg=""` before you can add strings to it with `+=`. Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/4c57ma5j/1/

```js
function pag_slider() {
    var pg = "";
    for(p=0;p<n_sliders;p++) {
        pg+="<span>"+p+"</span>";
    }
    $("#cont").html("<span>"+pg+"</span>");
}

n_sliders = 6;

pag_slider();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">
hello
</div>
```